# Making Premiere Pro Project Codecs Cross-Platform Compatible (Windows & Mac)

Tags: premiere, codec, windows, mac

I work on a Mac and I need to send a Premiere Pro CS6 project file to someone who works on Windows. He has QuickTime Pro 7 installed.

The project contains the following types of clip assets:

- Apple Animation (with alpha transparency) - .mov
- H.264 - .mov
- H.264 MPEG - .mp4

All sequences in the project have the following settings:

[image: Sequence settings]

When he tries to open the project in Windows, he gets the following error:

> This project contained a sequence that could not be opened. No sequence preview preset file or codec could be associated with this sequence type.

Could someone help me understand this error, and perhaps help in resolving this issue? Is it caused by missing codecs for the actual assets (I suspect the Apple Animation file) or simply by some settings in my project?

Comment: You could troubleshoot by removing that file and sending a test version. That said, Animation files work fine on my Windows machine. One thing that sticks out is the `quicktime (Desktop)` preview file format. Maybe change that to all I-Frame MPEG?

Comment: I don't have that format. All I have is these... http://i.imgur.com/MpNIMf2.png

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with a codec or Apple (I assume he/she has QT installed on the PC anyway).

Here's what's going on: the PC version of Premiere is cracked and/or was not fully installed/updated. As such it is indeed missing the "Sequence Presets" that you have on your Mac. Hence the translation problem.

By "Sequence Preset" I mean the DSLR, RED, etc presets you see when you decide to "Create a new sequence". A cracked and/or poorly installed copy of Premiere will have all the important presets missing.

I recommend getting your hands of a legit copy of the program or running a thorough update of the program (it should solve your issue then, if the PC version is legal). Et oui!

The "Sequence Presets" look like this on Premiere CC (and are very similar on CS6 and previous versions):

[image]